# On Select Radio button capture Label text

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
function select() {
  return ($('input[type=radio]:checked + label').text());
}
```

```html
<div class="push-right">
  <div class="radio inline">
    <input class="radio ui-helper-hidden-accessible" name="fadder_applicant_type_person" id="fadder-female" title="female" value="2" type="radio" style="display: none;"><span class="ui-radio ui-radio-state-checked ui-radio-checked"></span>
    <label for="fadder-female" class="ui-radio ui-radio-state-checked ui-radio-checked">
      Kvinna
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="radio inline">
    <input class="radio ui-helper-hidden-accessible" name="fadder_applicant_type_person" id="fadder-male" title="man" value="1" type="radio" style="display: none;"><span class="ui-radio"></span>
    <label for="fadder-male" class="ui-radio">
      Man
    </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

On Select Radio but want get text label on select if I selected radio button `fadder-male` text should be capture "Man"

Comment: @Satpal, not show select value http://www.barnfonden.se/bli-fadder

Answer (score 0):

If you want the text each time when the input changes then try the following

```
 $('input[type=radio]').on('change',function(){
    console.log($.trim($(this).siblings('label').text()));
 });
```

Comment: it calls only one time

Comment: So u want the text when the checkbox changes its value.Right?

Comment: That answer already provided by Satpal. Please come up with any new thing

Answer (score 0):

```
function labelValue(id){
 if($("#"+id).is(':checked')){
   var currlable = $("#"+id).siblings('label').text();
   return currlable;
 }
}

$("input[type=radio]").on("click",function(e){
  var id = $(this).attr("id");
  var labv = labelValue(id);
  alert(labv);
});
```

here is working fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/mcyee0eg/3/

Comment: Not showing text when i put like    function() {

        $(".radio").on("click",function(e){
  if($(this).is(':checked')) {

        var currlable = $(this).siblings('label').text();
    return currlable;
  }
})
    
  }

Comment: because you have not given any name to function?

Comment: Can you tell me what you want to include in function - http://screencast.com/t/Is8qRUF0

Comment: check now @MargubAlam

Comment: any input rajaesh

Comment: @MargubAlam have you got what you want?

Comment: complite error Error at line 9, character 1: Parse error. ')' expected

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try this:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<label for="demo">Demo</label>
<input type="radio" id="demo" />

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#demo").click(function(){
        alert($("label[for='demo']").html());
    });
});
</script>
```

Simple jquery code